# Заимствование слов

Tags: лексика, общие-вопросы, заимствования

Нужно ли освобождать русский язык от излишних заимствований?

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий, и общепринятого ответа на него нет, то есть предполагается дискуссия, а это выходит за рамки задач данного сайта.

Comment: Вопрос не совсем корректно сформулированный: кто будет "освобождать русский язык от излишних заимствований"?  Язык, с одной стороны, саморазвивающаяся система, а с другой - это система, регулируемая нормами. Даже если слово используется  в речи, это еще не значит, что оно будет нормировано.

Comment: Похоже на домашнее задание - тезис к сочинению о русском языке.

Comment: Ну тогда тезис некорректный, что еще хуже.

Answer (score 4):

Если уж вопрос не закрывают, то я отвечу на него кратко: **не надо освобождать.** Наш "великий и могучий" русский язык сам справится с этой задачей, оставив для себя только самое лучшее, что есть в других языках.

Также надо учитывать, что заимствованные слова могут являться **специальными терминами** или использоваться в определенных **социальных группах** как сленговые выражения, так что до статуса общелитературной лексики им нужно пройти долгий путь.

Но если искусственно ограждать себя от контакта с иноязычной лексикой, **то и развития не будет**. Об этом говорит как наш собственный опыт, так и опыт других стран.

Например, значительная часть лексики английского языка является заимствованной и относится к новому времени, то  есть **к периоду активных контактов и быстрого развития страны.** Возможно,  это стало одной из причин того, что он стал языком международного общения.

Answer (score 1):

В вопросе есть слово "излишних", являющееся ключевым.

В языке много заимствований - нужных, интересных, приятных. Но лично свой язык я стараюсь освобождать от таких, именно излишних заимствований, как:

*окей, в тренде, автопати* и т. д.